# Je ne réfléchis pas vraiment avant de poser de / un geste

Tags: articles

Bonjour,

> Je ne réfléchis pas vraiment avant de poser **de** geste, j’agis par intuition.

> Je ne réfléchis pas vraiment avant de poser **un** geste, j’agis par intuition.

Est-ce qu'il s'agit d'une négation ici en raison de "je ne réfléchis pas" "et donc il est préférable d'écrire "poser **de** geste" ou les deux options sont possibles ?

Answer (score 2):

Selon l'[office](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4439) québécois de la langue française, l'expression "poser un geste" est un régionalisme du Québec.

> En fait, cette locution est plutôt un régionalisme, c’est-à-dire qu’elle est utilisée seulement dans certaines régions de la francophonie. Car si poser un geste est employée relativement fréquemment au Québec, elle est pratiquement inusitée ailleurs dans la francophonie, notamment en France [...] **En Belgique**, on emploie une formule semblable, **poser un acte**, qui constitue elle aussi un régionalisme.
>
> [...]
>
> Dans un registre soigné ou lorsqu’on s’adresse à des locuteurs **non
> québécois**, on peut préférer éviter le régionalisme poser un geste. On
> peut alors le remplacer par les locutions **faire un geste**, accomplir un
> acte et commettre un acte, selon le contexte.

L'utilisation du "de" dans ta phrase n'est pas du bon français, car le "de" doit être utilisé avec le verbe qui utilise la négation.

- Je ne fais pas de gestes avant d'avoir réfléchi.
- Je ne réfléchis pas vraiment avant de faire un geste.
- Je ne réfléchis pas vraiment avant de ne pas faire de geste (phrase bizarre pour illustrer).
- (x) Je ne réfléchis pas vraiment avant de faire de geste.

J'utilise faire un geste dans mes exemples, mais le principe est le même pour poser un geste. On peut par contre utiliser "des gestes" et c'est probablement d'où l'erreur vient:

- Je ne réléchis pas vraiment avant de faire des gestes.

Comment: Merci. _"poser un geste" est un régionalisme du Québec_ --- Antidote ne dit rien à ce propos, cette expression est l'une des premières dans sa liste de cooccurrences.

Comment: @Oreste Je confirme que l'expression est inconnue pour moi.

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, toutes les sources d'Antidote contenant "poser un geste" sont canadiennes.